# Converting Int to Float without Rounding in F#

Tags: f#

I have code like this in F#

```
let fun a b=
  let mutable x1=float 0
  <some stuff>
   x1r<- -a/b

let main argv
    let  a=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) 
    let  b=Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
fun a b
```

And i have problem with converting -a/b to float. I tried oldschool *1.0f, and few other tricks, but none of them worked. Is there any way to convert this like that, or do i have to write it another way?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: btw, your code won't compile - please, provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried to divide -a by a. Both variables are ints

Comment: If you want to avoid rounding and/or the numerical precision issues with floats you should use a `Decimal` or `Rational` number type.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear but it looks like to me that you are dividing two `int` and expect that converting the result to a `float` would keep the fractional part but, when you divide two `int`s, you get back an `int` and converting it to a `float` cannot bring back the fractional part.

You should either convert both `a` and `b` to `float` before performing the division `(float -a) / (float b)` or, to begin with, read `float` values from the console with `Console.ReadLine() |> float`.